# VB6 : Can't find project or library when executing in office 2013

Tags: vb6

I am trying to run the vb6 code with 2013  office(Professional PLus) installed (upgraded from 2003) getting the "Can't find project or library" missing" error  . 
From where and how can I add the the reference for office 2013 . 
Thanks in advance . 
Please let me know if any more info required !

Comment: Why do you assume that the missing reference is Office 2013?

Comment: Because Office reference is the only one missing . When I open the reference dialog there is a checkbox ticked with empty line and only reference missing is of   MSOffice .

Comment: Ok.  I haven't used 2013 with VB6, but if you can find the location of the runtime file you can browse to it and select it in the References dialog.  One way to do that is look for one of the classes you are using in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT in the registry under CLASSID.

Comment: I am getting this error in one of the forms ... and suppose I find the class-id in the registry as mentioned then I get the Class ID value what should I do with that ! I am fairly new to VB6 just getting started here so pls bear the ignorance in these questions !

Comment: You don't add a reference for Office 2013 specifically.  If you're using Excel, you add the reference for Excel Automation.  If you're using Access, you need the one for Access, and so on.